# command not found in BASH

Tags: bash

I am getting `command not found`:

```
> sh readsdb.sh `pwd`/test 2
/home/lorencm/test 2
readsdb.sh: line 8: parallel: command not found
readsdb.sh: line 8: find: command not found
hello
readsdb.sh: line 10: parallel: command not found
readsdb.sh: line 10: find: command not found
readsdb.sh: line 10: sed: command not found
readsdb.sh: line 11: parallel: command not found
readsdb.sh: line 11: find: command not found
readsdb.sh: line 12: find: command not found
readsdb.sh: line 12: parallel: command not found

> parallel -h
Usage:
parallel [options] [command [arguments]] < list_of_arguments
```

with the below script

```
#!/bin/bash
module load fastqc/0.11.2-java-1.7.0_60

PATH="$1"
CPUS="$2"

echo $PATH $CPUS
find $PATH/*.gz -type f | parallel -j $CPUS "fastqc {}"
echo "hello"
find $PATH/*_fastqc.zip -type f | sed 's/\.zip$//' | parallel -j $CPUS 'unzip -c {}.zip {}/fastqc_data.txt | crimson fastqc /dev/stdin {}.json'
find $PATH/*_fastqc.zip -type f| parallel -j $CPUS 'dir={}; dir=${dir%.zip}; dir=${dir##*/}; unzip -c {} "$dir/fastqc_data.txt" | crimson fastqc /dev/stdin > {.}.json'
find $PATH/ -type f | parallel -j $CPUS md5sum '>' {}.md5
```

All programs are installed. What did I miss?

Thank you in advance.

Mic

Comment: Try using full paths. For example, instead of `find`, use `/usr/bin/find`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You set the [`PATH` environment variable](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PATH_(variable)), which is what `bash` uses to find programs. Since `PATH` no longer includes the directories which contain `parallel`, `find`, and `sed`, they can't be found by `bash`.

You should change the variable name you use from `PATH` to something else like `path`. You should also surround uses of variables with quotes, like this:

```
find "$path/*.gz" -type f | parallel -j "$CPUS" "fastqc {}"
```